# How do I set the default form in vb.Net?

Tags: vb.net

How do I set form number four as the default form that will run when I press on f5 in visual studio 2008. Because form 1 will always be the first to start

Comment: it can be done from project properties, right?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Right-click on your project in solution explorer.
2. Choose properties.
3. Select the Application Tab.
4. Select your form from the dropdown under 'startup form'

Comment: This works, but it will prevent the use of `ApplicationEvents` like `Startup`, because the startup object has to be `Sub Main` for these to work. You will have to change the default form in the application files to avoid this.

Answer (score 5):

In the Project Properties, there's a field called "Startup form" - select your form in there.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click your Project within the Solution Explorer.
Choose Properties.
Select the Web tab on the left-hand side.
Under the Start Page section, define the Specific Page you would like to default to when the application is launched.
Save your changes.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Right-click your Project** within the Solution Explorer.
2. Choose **Properties**.
3. Select the **Web** tab on the left-hand side.
4. Under the **Start Page** section, define the **Specific Page** you would
   like to default to when the application is launched.
   Save your changes.

[image: Illustration]

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions work, but they will prevent the use of `ApplicationEvents` like `Startup`, because the startup object has to be `Sub Main` for those to work.

This is btw also needed if you rename your default `Form1` to anything else, because VS doesn't auto-update the references for some reason.

**To change the form started by `Sub Main`**, do the following:

1. Close your project in Visual Studio.
2. Open your project's folder in explorer.
3. In it, open folder `My Project`.
4. Open `Application.myapp` with any text editor.
5. Change the form between the `<MainForm>` tags to your (new) main forms name.
6. Save and close.
7. Open `ApplicationDesigner.vb` with any text editor.
8. Find the following line and change *YourMainFormsName* to your (new) main forms name:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
    Me.MainForm = Global.YourProjectsName.YourMainFormsName
End Sub
```

9. Save and close.
10. Open your project again and start it up. The startup form should have changed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it doesn't work immediately from project properties. I have to close the solution and re-open it in order to see the latest form you have created and if you intend to make a startup object.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Basic 2022

1. In the Solution Explorer right click Project name and select Properties.
2. Under Application General scroll down to Startup Object
3. In the drop down select which form you want to start up with.