# How to change which form opens when starting a program in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, startup

I created a Windows Forms project in VB.net and I have decided to add another form to appear before Form1. How can I make a different form appear on start up instead of Form1?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set the default form in vb.Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370776/how-do-i-set-the-default-form-in-vb-net)

Comment: oops I believe it is a duplicate as well. what should I do now?

Comment: there should be a button to delete the question, right above these comments.

Comment: it says it cannot be deleted, only flag for moderator

Comment: Then just wait a bit, it's flagged already, it will soon be handled :)

Comment: am I going to get docked any points? or get a mark on permanent record?

Comment: It won't have any negative effects as far as I know, don't worry.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33139/discussion-between-jeremy-lin-and-stijn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the startup form in Windows Forms:

In `Solution Explorer`, right-click the project and choose `Properties`.

The `Project property` page opens with the General properties displayed.

Choose the form you want as the startup form from the `Startup Object` drop-down list.

Answer (score 2):

Open up your project properties (you can double-click on it in the Solution Explorer)
Go to `Application` > `Startup Form`

At least that's how I do it in VS 2010.

Hope that does the trick for you too...

Answer (score 0):

If this does not work I have another solution. go to **SOLUTION EXPLORER** , then open **PROGRAM.CS** (just click the down-arrow next to it) after that open **PROGRAM** (again just click the little down-arrow next to it) and double click **Main() : void** . That will take you to its code. Which will look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Ednevnik
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new LoginSystem());
        }
    }
}
```

In the last line you can see **LoginSystem()** (that is the name of the form that opens at the start) so you just have to change that to the name of the form you want to open.